# How do I find the percentage of similarity between two multiline Strings?

Tags: java, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

I have got two multi-line strings. I'm using the following code to determine the similarity between two of them.  This makes use of Levenshtein distance algorithm.

```
  public static double similarity(String s1, String s2) {
    String longer = s1, shorter = s2;
    if (s1.length() < s2.length()) { 
      longer = s2; shorter = s1;
    }
    int longerLength = longer.length();
    if (longerLength == 0) { return 1.0; /* both strings are zero length */ }

    return (longerLength - editDistance(longer, shorter)) / (double) longerLength;

  }

  public static int editDistance(String s1, String s2) {
    s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
    s2 = s2.toLowerCase();

    int[] costs = new int[s2.length() + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= s1.length(); i++) {
      int lastValue = i;
      for (int j = 0; j <= s2.length(); j++) {
        if (i == 0)
          costs[j] = j;
        else {
          if (j > 0) {
            int newValue = costs[j - 1];
            if (s1.charAt(i - 1) != s2.charAt(j - 1))
              newValue = Math.min(Math.min(newValue, lastValue),
                  costs[j]) + 1;
            costs[j - 1] = lastValue;
            lastValue = newValue;
          }
        }
      }
      if (i > 0)
        costs[s2.length()] = lastValue;
    }
    return costs[s2.length()];
  }
```

But the above code is not working as expected.

For instance lets say that we have got the following two strings say `s1` and `s2`,

S1 -> `How do we optimize  the performance? . What should we do to compare both strings to find the percentage of similarity between both?`

S2-> `How do we optimize tje performance? What should we do to compare both strings to find the percentage of similarity between both?`

Then I'm passing the above string to similarity method but it does not find the exact percentage of difference. How do I optimize the algorithm?

Following is my main method

**update**:

```
public static boolean authQuestion(String question) throws SQLException{


        boolean isQuestionAvailable = false;
        Connection dbCon = null;
        try {
            dbCon = MyResource.getConnection();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM WORDBANK where WORD ~*  ?;";
            PreparedStatement checkStmt = dbCon.prepareStatement(query);
            checkStmt.setString(1, question);
            ResultSet rs = checkStmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                double re=similarity( rs.getString("question"), question);
                if(re  > 0.6){
                    isQuestionAvailable = true;
                }else {
                    isQuestionAvailable = false;
                }
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (dbCon != null)
                dbCon.close();
        } finally {
            if (dbCon != null)
                dbCon.close();
        }

        return isQuestionAvailable;
    }
```

Comment: See if [Apache's implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.0/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java#StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Cjava.lang.CharSequence%29) gives you any ideas.

Comment: So, what percentage did you get, and what did you expect to get, and why? Also, what do you mean with "optimizing the algorithm"? Optimizing the performance, or do you mean "fixing" it until it does what you expected?

Comment: Fixing it unitl i get what I wanted. It prints 100 % all the time

Comment: I need to note that your code doesn't print anything. I just tried with the two strings you present in your code and it gives `96.94656488549618%` so not 100%. From which I conclude that possibly the problem is in the code that you use to print the output, or perhaps you're not running it correctly. Include your `main` method please.

Comment: I'm not sure what you intend to do with the SQL query. You won't find your S2 in the database if you search with your S1 string. The `~*` operator that you use in your query is the postgresql case-insensitive regular expression matching operator, but the strings that you are passing in are not regular expressions. So if it doesn't find a match in the database, your `while` loop is never entered, and `isQuestionAvailable` remains `false`.

Comment: Im comparing the existing values in database with the values that will be entered newly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can suggest you an approach...

You are using edit distance, which gives you the number of characters in S1 you need to change/add/remove in order to turn it to S2.

So, for example:

```
S1 = "abc"
S2 = "cde"
```

the edit distance is 3 and they are 100% different (taking in consideration you see it in some kind of char by char comparison).

So you can have an approximate percentage if you do

```
S1 = "abc"
S2 = "cde"
edit = edit_distance(S1, S2)
percentage = min(edit/S1.length(), edit/S2.length())
```

the min is a workaround to treat the cases where the strings are very different, for example:

```
S1 = "abc"
S2 = "defghijklmno"
```

so the edit distance would be bigger than the length of S1 and the percentage should be more than 100%, so maybe dividing by the bigger of the sizes should be better.

hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Your `similarity` method returns a number between 0 and 1 (both ends inclusive) where one means that the strings are the same (edit distance is zero).

However in your `authQuestion` method you are acting as if it returns a number between zero and 100, evidenced by this line:

```
if(re > 60){
```

You need to change that to

```
if(re > .6){
```

Or to

```
if(re * 100 > 60){
```

Comment: i have tried it but still it is not working as expected

Comment: I have used re ? .6 but the loop always returns false. It returns true if and only the code does not enter the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using your entire S1 in the *where clause* of your sql query, it will either find a perfect match or won't return any result at all.

As mentioned by @ErwinBolwidt, if it **returns nothing** then you `isQuestionAvailable` will always remain **false**. 
And if it returns a **perfect match** then you are bound to get **100% similarity**.

What you can do is: Use a **substring of your S1** to search for questions that match that part.

You can make following changes:

`authQuestion method`

```
checkStmt.setString(1, question.substring(0,20)); //say
```

Out of the results fetched, you can compare each result with your question for similarity.